# TypeScript not recognizing values set on object within scope of a forEach loop before its passed as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Im trying to pass an object prop into a functional component that has a prop type definition. I first set the value for each of the required prop type attributes within the scope of a forEach loop, which TypeScript cant seem to recognize:

```
const preparePayload = (initPayload) => {
  const initSubmissionState = {'e':'e'}
  const attributes = ['a', 'b', 'c','d']

  attributes.forEach (a => {
    if (initPayload.suggested_attributes && initPayload.suggested_attributes[a]) {
      initSubmissionState[a] = initPayload.suggested_attributes[a]
    } else if (initPayload[a]){
      initSubmissionState[a] = initPayload[a]
    } else{
      initSubmissionState[a] = ''
    }
  })
  return initSubmissionState
}

interface Component2Props {
  a: string,
  b: string,
  c: string,
  d: string
}

const Component2 = (props:Component2Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>{props.a}</div>
      <div>{props.b}</div>
      <div>{props.c}</div>
      <div>{props.d}</div>
    </>
  )
}

const initPayload = {
  a: 'a',
  c: 'c',
  suggested_attributes: {
    a:'A'
  }
}

const Component = (props) => {
  const payload = preparePayload(props)

  return (
    <Component2 {...payload} />
  )
}
```

I am getting a type error passing the payload into Component2:
`Type '{ e: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Component2Props': a, b, c, d`

Do I have to explicitly set each of the attributes in the helper function for TypeScript to allow it as props?

Comment: Everyone should be avoiding `.forEach` because it introduces a closure scope [and other issues](https://betterprogramming.pub/should-you-stop-using-foreach-in-your-javascript-code-efe1e86c78e5). What happens if you use a `for(of)` loop?

Comment: forEach is fine.... just someone's opinion it is bad

Comment: @Dai that is still giving me the same error.

Comment: something like `forEach((a:Component2Props) => ...`

Comment: Reason you do not use Object.assign with default values? `const preparePayload = (initPayload): Component2Props => {
  return Object.assign({ a: '', b: '', c: '', d: 'd' }, initPayload);
}`

Comment: @epascarello this does work, however my actual `forEach` logic was more complex than what I included in the code. I edited to reflect my problem more accurately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two components to your issue. First you try to assign unknown keys (`a`, `b` and `c`) to your object `initSubmissionState`, which only knows the property `d`. Short example:

```
const initSubmissionState = { d:'d' }
initSubmissionState.a = 'a'
```

[TypeScript Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmOUDKBXARgWzhCdzJQCGUApjALwwDeMAJgFwDkdTMAvgFAJJpY54CxMgDoilGEyJNOQA)

Solution: give explicit typings to your variable `initSubmissionState`:

```
const initSubmissionState: Partial<Record<'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd', string>> = { d:'d' }
initSubmissionState.a = 'a'
```

[TypeScript Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmOUDKBXARgWzhCdzJQCGUApgFwwAKRATlHEQDYA8ASqaLQCYsDkRPjAA%20MPuiGi%20wSWO58ANDGi0EAcwB8GmAF4YAbxjdyfeTAC%20AKARI0WHHgLEyAOiK6xgy0A)

The second component is that typescript can't properly interfere the type of your `attributes` array. It by default selects the smallest common supertype for the array, in this example `string`, which means the following won't work:

```
const initSubmissionState: Partial<Record<'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd', string>> = { d:'d' }
const attributes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
attributes.forEach(attr => {
  // TypeScript interferes attr to be of type string, not 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd'
  initSubmissionState[attr] = '' // error because initSubmissionState only has keys 'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd' but TypeScript thinks attr is any string
})
```

The last step is to now let TypeScript properly interfere the type of your `attributes` array:

```
const asStringLiteralArray = <T extends string>(...values: T[]) => values

const initSubmissionState: Partial<Record<'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd', string>> = { d:'d' }
const attributes = asStringLiteralArray('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
attributes.forEach(attr => {
  initSubmissionState[attr] = ''
})
```

[TypeScript Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhhAylATgSzAcwDJqgUxTgBsBBFIgTxgF4YAeAFRnwA8CwATCGadLAHwAKAHRiAbiQCu%20CAC4YjANoBdAJS0BMScRkQAUPtCRYGPIikAjALZoIENOGRwCCgApwUUNCXoAlfFAUTnoAcjhQmAAfGFDLSJjQ4ATYzlCAGl5UDEwBLToAbxhOOVC0mABfI3BoeChsyykCHjoEZH4cPEISciohcIzY%20MykwbLQtX0XBqbZEQAzEBQAUThgAAshaZRNGAL9GBgzKAsbOwcnKBd8JW2VWljQ-QrJoA)

Let's now put it all together:

```
const preparePayload = (initPayload: Record<string, string>) => {
  const initSubmissionState: Partial<Component2Props> = {'d':'d'}
  attributes.forEach(a => {
    if (a in initPayload) {
      initSubmissionState[a] = initPayload[a]
    } else {
      initSubmissionState[a] = ''
    }
  })

  return initSubmissionState as Component2Props
}

const asStringLiteralArray = <T extends string>(...values: T[]) => values
const attributes = asStringLiteralArray('a', 'b', 'c','d')

type Component2Props = Record<typeof attributes[0], string>;

const Component2 = (props:Component2Props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>{props.a}</div>
      <div>{props.b}</div>
      <div>{props.c}</div>
    </>
  )
}

const initPayload = {
  a: 'a',
  c: 'c'
}

const Component = (props) => {
  const payload = preparePayload(props)

  return (
    <Component2 {...payload} />
  )
}
```

Edit: Please try to build a minimal executable example next time, this would enable others to try their fixes without much additional work.